# Webview works for iphone but not for ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mobile, ios5

below code is working on Iphone, I am having an issue with the webview loading on ipad, it hits the didFailwith error, (iPad is connected) any help appreciated?

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
      NSURL *url;
      if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
          url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
      }else{
          url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
      }
      NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
      [webSurfForecast loadRequest:req];
      [super viewDidAppear:YES];
  }

 -(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Can't connect. Please check your          internet Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
}
```

Comment: have you checked what actually is in the NSError error variable?

Comment: Hi Bastian, new enough to this, NSError is: Error ipad Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (WebKitErrorDomain error 101.)" UserInfo=0x7064c50 {}

Comment: are you actually trying with http://www.google.com ? The error sounds like you are using an url without urlencoding it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check like this..

```
  BOOL iPad = NO;
  #ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
  iPad = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
  #endif
  if (iPad) {
            // iPad specific code here
   } else {
            // iPhone/iPod specific code here
   }
```

Comment: Hi Anshul, This answer is not related to my issue, my code to check device works.